# "Радуюсь(,) как за себя" — сравнительный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, сравнительный-оборот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении:
***Радуюсь(,) как за себя***?

Думается, что нет, поскольку оборот тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым. Это так?

Answer (score 3):

Чисто интуитивно я поставила бы запятую, считая, что это неполное (сложноподчиненное) предложение:
***Радуюсь*** [так], **как** [радовалась бы] **за себя**.

Но в других случаях оборот можно считать необособленным обстоятельством:
***Он был так доволен, радовался как за себя.***

Наверное, в *разных* случаях возможно *разное* решение.

Comment: Спасибо!
А можно тогда и значение подобия здесь увидеть? Например: радуюсь, подобно тому, как радовался бы за себя.

Comment: Радуюсь, подобно тому как радовался бы за себя.Мне кажется, что значения сравнения и уподобления близки здесь между собой.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна: http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=154#pp154, п. 4.
2) если основное значение оборота — приравнивание или отождествление: …Ты любил меня как собственность, как источник радостей, тревог и печалей (Л.)